# Delete a dynamic key from a TypeScript object

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, ecma

In TypeScript it is quite simple to clone an object:

`const a = {...b}`

or clone and update

`const a = {...b, c: 'd'}`

So for example, I have this code:

```
const a = {
    'something': 1,
    'e': 2,
};
const c = 'something';
delete a[c];
```

Is there a nice way to delete a property of that object, instead of using the traditional
`delete a[c]` way? (of course also not `a[c] = undefined`)

Comment: I think you're looking for `const { [c]: _, ...withootC } = a;`

Comment: ah, awesome. Could you add an answer and explain how it works, this is what I've looked for

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You're looking for combination of computed property names and destructuring. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring)

```
const a = {
    'something': 1,
    'e': 2,
};

const c = 'something';

const { [c]: _, ...withoutC } = a;
```

Here we're putting value of property *something* (taken from `c` variable) into `_` variable and all the other props go to `withoutC` variable. The fact that `c` defined as `const` allows typescript to infer the type of `withoutC` properly.

Answer (score 8):

Rather than deleting the property from `a`, use destructured assignment to create a new object without that property:

```
const {c, ...b} = a;
```

After this `b` will contain all members of `a` except `c`.

Given that `a` is some type, say, `{ c: string, d: string }` the types of `c` and `b` will be inferred to be `string` and `{ d: string }` respectively. Of course, if you have to explicitly write these type annotations, using an `Omit` type as  [@Nurbol Alpybayev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54749298/1715579) suggests is usually a lot better than having to spell out the types in long form.

You can rename `c` to avoid conflicts with another name using this syntax:

```
const {c: someOtherName, ...b} = a;
```

The above method will work if you know the property name at compile time. If that's not the case in your scenario, then the TypeScript compiler can't really help you that much because it won't be able to determine the result type of the operation.

You'd be better off typing `a` as `{ [k: string]: number }`, in which case `delete a[c]` would be fine, or you could use something like the following:

```
const exclude = <T>(map: { [k: string]: T }, omitted: string[]): { [k: string]: T } =>
  return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a)
    .filter(k => omitted.indexOf(k) >= 0)
    .reduce((a, k) => (a[k] = map[k], a), {})
};
var b = exclude(a, ["c"]);
```

Comment: Really close, but in my case, it is a bit more complicated. For example: ```const a = {
    'something': 1,
    'e': 2,
};
const c = 'something';
const { 'something': undefined, ...b } = a;``` work, but ```const a = {
    'something': 1,
    'e': 2,
};
const c = 'something';
const { c: undefined, ...b } = a;``` doesn't

Comment: so the point here is ```c``` is not a string ```'c'```. It is a variable ```const c = 'something'```. Hope this time it is clear enough

Comment: @NguyenPhongThien I'm still not sure if I understand the problem. If the property that you want to delete is known at compile time, my method will work. If the property name isn't known at compile time, the result type of the expression cannot be determined (except for mapped types like `{ [k: string]: number }`).

Comment: no, it is not a problem at all. I'm finding a nicer way to clone an object and delete a key from that, instead of ```const a = {...b}; delete a[c];``` and sometime later ```b = {...a}```. Because I don't want to mutate the original object for a while. But if it is not possible, it will still not be a big issue

Comment: @NguyenPhongThien I've added one more solution that's more idiomatic than `const a = {...b}; delete a[c];`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure! You can do this using `Omit` type:

```
type Omit<T, K> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>

type DeleteBar = Omit<{bar: 123, baz: 123}, 'bar'> // {baz: 123}
```

P.S. I realized that you might have asked about values, not types. You should have ask about javascript probably, not typescript.

Comment: it doesn't really work, could you please let me know how does it work in this case: ```const a = {
    'something': 1,
    'e': 2,
};
const c = 'something';
delete a[c];```